# Anchor IdlError: Type not Found for usize

Tags: anchor, idl, decode

When parsing an account using Anchor, I receive the following error:

```
IdlError: Type not found: "type":{"defined":"usize"}
```

**My code**

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import NodeWallet from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import ThreadProgram from "./thread_program.json";

async function main() {
  let connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
  let wallet = new NodeWallet(new Keypair());
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
    commitment: "processed",
  });

  const programId = ThreadProgram.metadata.address;
  const program = new anchor.Program(
    ThreadProgram as anchor.Idl,
    programId,
    provider
  );

  let thread = new PublicKey("HfvZbTxxnkRV3afvJfETiWwXoarYHbuAq4n34DUMzAsf");
  const parsed = await program.account.thread.fetch(thread);
  console.log(parsed);
}
```

Part of the IDL:

```
              {
                "name": "size",
                "docs": [
                  "The size of the byte slice to monitor (must be less than 1kb)"
                ],
                "type": {
                  "defined": "usize"
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Solana eBPF `usize` and `isize` are equivalent to `u64` and `i64` respectively.
Change the following to

```
              {
                "name": "size",
                "docs": [
                  "The size of the byte slice to monitor (must be less than 1kb)"
                ],
                "type": "u64"
              }
```